# How to pass drop down selected value from pug view file in express js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

Totally I am new to Node.js and the task is to pass user selected value from the drop-down (View Engine used is Pug) and the value to be inserted in the DB. I am using Express.js for doing this.

Please guide me here with useful reference links or with any sample codes.
Please find my pug file as below

`

```
doctype html
html
    head
        script(src="/javascripts/script.js")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/style.css")
        h4=page_title
    body
        span Sort by
        select(name = 'sorting' id = 'sort' onchange = 'onSorting()')
            option Sort by
            option(value = 'asc') Asc
            option(value = 'desc') Desc
            option(value = 'top 5') Top 5
            option(value = 'bottom 5') Bottom 5
        table#desc
            tr
                th ID
                th Name
                th Email
            each users in userdetail
                tr
                    td= users.id
                    td= users.name
                    td= users.email
html
```

`

and js file as below

`

```
function onSorting(){
    console.log("hi");
    document.getElementsByName('sorting');
    window.location = "/users?input=" + $(this).val();
}
```

`

Comment: Where are your codes?

Comment: you will need to send data back to your server, probably via an AJAX call to an UPDATE/POST route.